# Where did the Kubuntu 15.04 iso images go?

Tags: kubuntu, 15.04

It seems that the 15.04 Kubuntu iso images have "disappeared".  They are not available on any of the mirrors and archives.

Neither cdimage:
http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/kubuntu/releases/
Or Old releases:
http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/kubuntu/

have a copy.

I get that even releases are the ones kept for a long time, but the odd releases serve a purpose when you have an unfixed bug and must roll back to a stable working version.

Where can one get Kubuntu 15.04 iso?

Comment: You won't fix anything rolling back to an EoL release. Use the current LTS, 16.04 or the previous one, 14.04.

Comment: @CelticWarrior We do when it' something like this afaik

Comment: Rolling back even further to 14.04 is a much better idea because 14.04 is still supported.

Comment: @Anwar - When it's something like what, exactly? What could possibly be solved by using the 15.04 ISO that can't be using 16.04 LTS?

Comment: The graphics drivers for Nvidia 1060 do not work on 16.04, or 14.04.  Only on 15.04.  So the only choice is to use 15.04 until a workaround exits.

Comment: Sorry but that is simply not true.

Comment: Even if that is true, you can run 14.04.3, and that should solve whatever problem you are claiming is only solved by running 15.04.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/1298573/925128

Answer (score 1):

Old releases can be found on the archives site.

- [kUbuntu](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/kubuntu/)
- [Ubuntu](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/)

But it seems kUbuntu has not been updated ... 12.04.4 is the newest I could find there where the Ubuntu site has been updated.

Your approach is not a good one. I would advice to stick to current releases, prefer LTS, file a issue against the bug and push for it to get fixed. Using 14.04 is a far better approach: it is still current, gets updates for hardware and security and allows you to upgrade to 16.04 when your problem is fixed.

> I get that even releases are the ones kept for a long time, but the odd releases serve a purpose when you have an unfixed bug and must roll back to a stable working version.

I disagree. It would even be far better to install 14.04, identify the package that causes problems for you and download the 15.04 version and install that in 14.04. Still can be a security issue due but it is far better than using an OS that has been dropped.

---

The 1060 works with 16.04. Fix the reason why you can not get 16.04 installed. Proof: [phoronix](http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=article&item=nv-linux-gtx1060&num=1) article using 16.04, Unity 7.4 and nVidia driver 367.27 with the GTX 1060. [nvidia](http://www.nvidia.com/download/driverResults.aspx/106780/en-us) also lists the GTX 1060 as supported with their driver version 367.44.

And [here](http://tipsonubuntu.com/2016/08/24/nvidia-367-44-support-titan-x-pascal-gtx-1060/) someone that posted a how to on how to get the GTX 1060 working on 14.04, 16.04 and 16.10.

Comment: 14.04 is not an option unfortunately.  Tried and failed. There is a bug in the only Nvidia driver that supports the 1060. On 14.04 you get unusable graphics.  On 16.04 you get an unbootable system.
15.04 does work with it.. Which is why Id love to roll back to a working system until there is a workaround for 16.04 or 14.04.

Comment: Not true. 14.04 = 14.04+14.10 (=14.04.2)+15.04 (=14.04.3)+15.10 (=14.05.4)in regards of hardware. If it works on 15.04 so does it work in 14.04.3.  And so does it work on 15.10 and 16.04 (by installing manually that old driver). But as added to the question: the GTX 1060 works in 16.04 so please focus on solving your problem from 16.04.

Comment: I have already followed both those tutorials. Both of them produce dead ends and unworkable systems. There are specific reasons why it ONLY works correctly on 15.04.   16.04 and 14.04 arent an option.

I had it working perfectly on 15.04 without any of the bugs that are present in 14.04 or 16.04.  Reverting to 15.04 is the best solution until the issues with 16.04 are fixed.

Comment: One of the hurdles is simply the Plasma versions in play which of course creates a hell of other pre-requisites.  Plasma 5.2 works (kubuntu 15.04), Plasma 5.4 (Kubuntu 16.04) and later does not. 

This issue is not the same on ubuntu.. So to be clear yes I could use Ubuntu, but as I said the easiest and best solution is "Where did the Kubuntu 15.04 images go to"?

Comment: The 15.04 kUbuntu ISO went into oblivion.   End of life means dead. 15.04 if you even get it you can not even update it so installing software is a no-go anyways. Again: 14.04(.3) when concerning plasma,  hardware and drivers is 100% equal to 15.04.

Comment: I have tried 14.04.03 iso, updating it as far as it goes, and it is not the same. Not even close. I have another system running 15.04 to compare it to.  Cant get it to the same set of packages as 15.04, as there are unmet dependencies.

So PLEASE.. If either 14.04 or 16.04 were a solution Id very happily use them.  They are not. FWIW 16.04 ubuntu does work just not Kubuntu 16.04.

Comment: I have now tried:
14.0.2, 14.04.03, 14.04.05  All retain the issues that make 14.x unusable..

I now have a link to download kubuntu 15.04 from the evga team..