# All Kubuntu releases?

Tags: kubuntu, repository, release-management

I would like to know if **ALL Kubuntu releases** are available in the way the Ubuntu-proper releases are at http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/, from 4.10 to 20.10

I would like to take a look at some Plasma [features that might have been added and then removed](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/623290/341192).

Before 15.04 there is no Plasma 5, and *I have tested already the LTS releases after that*. — Therefore, what mostly interests me would be the **non-LTS ("normal") releases from 15.04 to 17.10**. (I would take a look even at 18.10 and 19.04, but I cannot find them either.)

I have found **ALL LTS VERSIONS [here](https://soft.lafibre.info/)**.

(***EDIT***: also, as posted in a comment below, [here](https://cdimage.ubuntu.com/kubuntu/releases/) are recent LTS releases, starting with 16.04.)

**ALL VERSIONS up to 11.10** [here](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/kubuntu/).

Comment: This can be helpful: https://cdimage.ubuntu.com/kubuntu/releases/

Comment: If I'm not wrong, the first Kubuntu version is 5.04.

Comment: @RandomPerson - `the first Kubuntu version is 5.04`. That's no problem, up to 11.10 they are [all here](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/kubuntu/) anyway.  The link you mention gives only post-16.04 LTS, which are also available as said in question - [here](https://soft.lafibre.info/) (ALL LTS are there in fact). But I'm looking for *non-LTS versions: mostly from 15.04 to 17.10*

Comment: A recent clean up was done, and it was discovered a flaw existed in the script that moved ISOs to old-releases, so some ISOs for *flavors* didn't get saved, others are. It was just noted, documented (via announcement) but nothing can be done for unsaved ISOs.

Comment: @guiverc - Could you post that as a short answer? I could make the question more specific. I guess it's just some *interim* releases.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Kubuntu 15.04: https://web.archive.org/web/20151110133002/http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/kubuntu/releases/vivid/release/
- Kubuntu 15.10: https://web.archive.org/web/20160517131813/http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/kubuntu/releases/15.10/release/
- Kubuntu 16.10: https://web.archive.org/web/20170606120152/http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/kubuntu/releases/16.10/release/
- Kubuntu 17.04: https://web.archive.org/web/20171222021400/http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/kubuntu/releases/17.04/release
- Kubuntu 17.10: https://web.archive.org/web/20180628191845/http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/kubuntu/releases/17.10.1/release/
- Kubuntu 18.10: https://web.archive.org/web/20190629160724/http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/kubuntu/releases/18.10/release/
- Kubuntu 19.04:

  - https://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/kubuntu/releases/19.04/release/
  - https://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/kubuntu/releases/disco/release/

Answer (score 2):

A recent clean up was done and some flaws were discovered

Steve Langasek (vorlon) writes

> ... In the process, I also discovered that the point release process
> as documented on https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PointReleaseProcess with
> regards to archival of prior point release artifacts has not been
> followed for some time, and while not-current point release images for
> releases.ubuntu.com were properly being moved to old-releases, the
> **stale point release images for flavors on cdimage.ubuntu.com were not**
> **being archived.**  Because this was never a documented policy change,
> I've followed through on the missing step and taken down these various
> stale point release images (most of which, it should be noted, have an
> apt that's vulnerable to a known MITM attack and should not be used
> under any conditions).

https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-release/2020-October/005113.html

Comment: there might have been another *related* announcement too, but that's what I found..